# Avoiding race conditions while sending to channel?

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock

go version go1.11.2 darwin/amd64

I have the following code sample, created for SO demo purposes:

```
package main

import (
    ...
)

type T struct {
    ctx context.Context
    ch1 chan string
}

func New(ctx context.Context) *T {
    t := &T{ctx: ctx}
    go t.run(2)
    return t

}

func (t *T) run(workers int) {
    t.ch1 = make(chan string)
    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        <-t.ctx.Done()
        close(done)
        close(t.ch1)
    }()

    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case <-done:
                    return
                case m, ok := <-t.ch1:
                    if ok {
                        t.process(done, m)
                    }
                }
            }
        }()
    }
}

func (t *T) process(done <-chan struct{}, s string) {
    select {
    case <-done:
        return
    default:
        log.Printf("processing %s", s)
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 200)
    }
}

func (t *T) Read() <-chan string {
    return t.ch1
}

func (t *T) Write(s string) error {
    select {
    case <-t.ctx.Done():
        return errors.New("consumer is closed today")
    case t.ch1 <- s:
        return nil
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    t := New(ctx)

    go func() {
        for m := range t.Read() {
            log.Printf("got %s", m)
        }
        <-ctx.Done()
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        t.Write(strconv.Itoa(i))
    }
    cancel()
}
```

When I build and run this with the race detector, it throws the following data race:

```
go build -race ./test/ && ./test
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000b6030 by goroutine 7:
  main.main.func1()
      /redacted/test/app.go:60 +0x42

Previous write at 0x00c0000b6030 by goroutine 6:
  main.(*T).run()
      /redacted/test/app.go:24 +0x6a

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /redacted/test/app.go:76 +0xbc

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.New()
      /redacted/test/app.go:18 +0xcd
  main.main()
      /redacted/test/app.go:74 +0x86
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000b6030 by main goroutine:
  main.(*T).Write()
      /redacted/test/app.go:67 +0x8a
  main.main()
      /redacted/test/app.go:84 +0xdc

Previous write at 0x00c0000b6030 by goroutine 6:
  main.(*T).run()
      /redacted/test/app.go:24 +0x6a

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.New()
      /redacted/test/app.go:18 +0xcd
  main.main()
      /redacted/test/app.go:74 +0x86
==================
2019/01/20 10:48:51 got 0
2019/01/20 10:48:51 got 3
2019/01/20 10:48:51 processing 1
2019/01/20 10:48:51 processing 2
2019/01/20 10:48:51 got 4
2019/01/20 10:48:51 got 5
2019/01/20 10:48:51 got 6
2019/01/20 10:48:51 got 7
2019/01/20 10:48:51 got 8
2019/01/20 10:48:51 got 9
Found 2 data race(s)
```

The problem I'm getting is that I can't seem to find a way to have a user input something in to a channel, without exposing any channel for writes, without a race. How would this be possible? Is there a better pattern for this that I am missing?

Comment: A read or write to a channel cannot race, your problem is creating the channel in another goroutine, far too late.

Comment: Where would you suggest I create them? I put them in the New function, but then they're not close to where they're being used, and then I end up getting things like send on closed channel.

Comment: Create them in `New`, thats where its supposed to happen. If you're getting another error then thats another problem in your code somewhere.

Comment: You shouldn't close ch1. You already have context cancellation as the abort condition in Read. Closing the channel is redundant and unsafe since it races against the context.

Comment: @Peter Shouldn't you *always* close your channels?

Comment: No. You only have to close channels if something is looking for a close (such as a range loop). That's entirely your decision.

Comment: Ah. In this situation I do want to close my channels so the user can range over the channels. Trying to see how I can close the channels and stop writing to them at the same time.

Comment: You posted a fairly sizable code sample without much background on *what you are trying to accomplish*. What do you expect this code to do, and why?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making the following changes:

- assign to `ch1` in `New` to avoid the race of reading and writing to `t.ch1` in multiple goroutines
- only close `ch1` once all the calls to `Write` have finished to avoid "send on closed channel" panics
- use a `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for all the processing goroutines to finish after writing all the values (so that the program doesn't exit before processing has finished)

Bringing these changes together, here's how it would look:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type T struct {
    // ch1 receives the values to process
    ch1 chan string

    // wg is used to wait for the workers to stop
    wg sync.WaitGroup
}

func New() *T {
    t := &T{
        ch1: make(chan string),
    }
    go t.run(2)
    return t
}

func (t *T) run(workers int) {
    // add the workers to the WaitGroup
    t.wg.Add(workers)

    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        go func() {
            // process values from the channel until it closes
            // and then signal to the WaitGroup that we're done
            defer t.wg.Done()
            for m := range t.ch1 {
                t.process(m)
            }
        }()
    }
}

// Stop is called after we're done calling Write and we want to stop the
// processing once all values have been processed
func (t *T) Stop() {
    // close t.ch1 so that the workers know to stop processing
    close(t.ch1)

    // wait for the workers to all finish before returning
    t.wg.Wait()
}

func (t *T) process(s string) {
    log.Printf("processing %s", s)
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 200)
}

func (t *T) Write(s string) {
    t.ch1 <- s
}

func main() {
    // start the main loop
    t := New()

    // write 10 values
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        t.Write(strconv.Itoa(i))
    }

    // stop the loop, which will wait for processing to finish before returning
    t.Stop()
}
```